# Java Null Pointer Exception in Queue

Tags: java, exception, pointers, null, queue

I have been trying to write a queue that uses a Node file, and I can't seem to figure out where the null pointer exception is an issue. I looked online a bit but I'm too new to Java I think to understand what I'm looking for here. Can anyone find it or at least lead me in the right direction??

First the Queue:

```
public class Queue extends CharNode {
public CharNode head;
public CharNode tail;

public Queue(){
    this.head = null;
    this.tail = null;}

public boolean isEmpty(){
    return (head==null);}

public void enqueue(Character character){
    if (isEmpty()){
        head.character = character;
        head.nextNode = tail;}
    else {
        CharNode oldTail = tail;
        tail = new CharNode();
        oldTail.character = character;
        oldTail.nextNode = tail;
    }
    }

public Character dequeue(){
    if (isEmpty()) throw new RuntimeException("Queue Empty");
    head.character = character;
    head = head.nextNode;
    return character;
}       
public static void main(String[] args){
    Queue queue = new Queue();
    queue.enqueue('a');
    queue.enqueue('b');
    System.out.print(queue.dequeue());
}
```

}

My CharNode file looks like:

```
public class CharNode {
public Character character;
public CharNode nextNode;
public void charNode(Character character){
    this.character = character;
    this.nextNode = null;
}
```

}

And the exception I received looks like:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Queue.enqueue(Queue.java:14)
at Queue.main(Queue.java:32)
```

Comment: To start with, `Queue` shouldn't extend `CharNode`; there's no *is-a* relationship there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public boolean isEmpty(){
    return (head==null);}

public void enqueue(Character character){
    if (isEmpty()){
        head.character = character;   // you have just said that head is NULL
```

What may work is

```
if (isEmpty()){
        head = new CharNode ();     // There is no Constructor for CharNode (Character)
        head.character = character;
```

Comment: Got to be the first time I've seen a null-check in the form of `if (object == null) // do something with that object`.

Comment: You must lead a sheltered life ;-)  Quite often maybe a `!` is missed off

Comment: I'm confused then, I want to assign the head only if the queue is empty, that way I can hold to the FIFO without an iterator. Wouldn't this be represented by the head being a null value? what am I not getting here?

Comment: You need to instantiate a new `head` CharNode before assigning to it.

Answer (score 0):

isEmpty() returns true if head is null. And you try to use a null object's value at enqueue method() which causes NPE.
This line:
head.character = character;